# cannot proceed "$ echo prog1/p*." command

Tags: linux

I am currently reading "**The LPI Introductory Programme**".
It says that I can try `$ echo prog1/p*.c` to search exact files that starts with "**p**" and ends with "**c**".

But instead of that, `echo` command just prints out the given in quotes, why ?

Comment: Probably because there are no files matching that pattern. Are you sure that you have a directory prog1 including c files starting with the letter p ?

Comment: yes, i create files with that parameters and it doesn't show them. It just prints out  just like echo ordinary does. IT just prints out "prog1/p*.c" I mean is it possible that writer of book made mistake. And Echo command cannot be used for that purpose?

Comment: Can you provide the exact output, and what you are expecting the output to look like?

Comment: sh-4.3$ touch pandoc pinoc                                                                                                   
sh-4.3$ ls                                                                                                                   
pandoc  pinoc                                                                                                                
sh-4.3$ echo prog1/p*.c

Comment: the output is prog1/p*.c

Comment: sorry, but comment did not let to copy and paste it one under another as usual code. so it got into the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` attempts to print file names that matches the given pattern, but if no match is found it treats pattern as text to be printed and does what it is meant for.

use `ls -l prog1/p*.c` instead, for listing files.
also make sure your current working directory and navigable sub directories from there.

Comment: That has nothing to do with echo. The shell tries to match that glob, and if there is no match the glob stays as is, e.g. it behaves as if the pattern was enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: i am agree, but actually i recheck it i create matching files i stay within the folder but  it just prints out the matching ones. I searched google before asking it here and could not find any info. nobody uses echo to make search. I just have behavior to not pass the chapter if something not clear. Or it is a mistake left by writer or i as nobody uses that it is not popular

Comment: can i paste screenshot to comment? is it possible?

Comment: Cliff can you please share the output of "ls -l pr*". 
Book is not wrong. 
I am not sure about Peter's comment.

Comment: ls: cannot access pr*: No such file or director

Comment: I hope you got it. :). now try "echo p*.c"

Comment: Thank you very much Rohit))) Thank man! I got it. i don't even know how to score your comment. Newbie here. Pls tell me how and i  will score it plz